# creating a multivariate skew normal distribution python

Tags: python, matplotlib, gaussian, surface

How can I create a multivariate skew normal function, where then by inputting x and y points we can create a surface diagram in 3d (x,y and z coordinates)

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html I think this is what you need

Comment: thank you for that! but how could i add skew to that? by modulating the covariance?

Comment: @SohrabSalimian , have you had the chance to solve your question? I am looking for the exact same thing. I found some work done in R in the library https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sn/index.html

Comment: I just realized that scipy.stats.skewnorm takes 2d input

Comment: @simon, this doesn't do what you want. `skewnorm(a=1).pdf(x=[1, 1])` returns two probabilities, not one. So it is evaluating each component of `x` with the same univariate distribution.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a [blog post](http://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2020/12/29/multivariate-skew-normal/) about this, but here is complete working code:

```py
from   matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from   scipy.stats import (multivariate_normal as mvn,
                           norm)


class multivariate_skewnorm:
    
    def __init__(self, a, cov=None):
        self.dim  = len(a)
        self.a    = np.asarray(a)
        self.mean = np.zeros(self.dim)
        self.cov  = np.eye(self.dim) if cov is None else np.asarray(cov)

    def pdf(self, x):
        return np.exp(self.logpdf(x))
        
    def logpdf(self, x):
        x    = mvn._process_quantiles(x, self.dim)
        pdf  = mvn(self.mean, self.cov).logpdf(x)
        cdf  = norm(0, 1).logcdf(np.dot(x, self.a))
        return np.log(2) + pdf + cdf


xx   = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
yy   = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)
pos  = np.dstack((X, Y))

fig  = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=150)
axes = [
    fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1, projection='3d'),
    fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2, projection='3d'),
    fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3, projection='3d')
]

for a, ax in zip([[0, 0], [5, 1], [1, 5]], axes):
    Z = multivariate_skewnorm(a=a).pdf(pos)
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.viridis)
    ax.set_title(r'$\alpha$ = %s, cov = $\mathbf{I}$' % str(a), fontsize=18)
```

That code will generate this figure:

[image: Examples of multivariate skew normal distributions]

Answer (score -2):

You can add direction to multivariate normal distribution by adding a sigma covariance matrix:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

mu = [20,20] # center of distribution.
sigma_size_top, sigma_size_bot = np.random.uniform(5, 20, size=2)
cov_max = np.sqrt(sigma_size_top * sigma_size_bot) * 0.9 # Cov max can't be larger than sqrt of the other elements
sigma_cov = np.random.uniform(-cov_max, cov_max)
sigma = np.array([[sigma_size_top, sigma_cov],[sigma_cov, sigma_size_bot]])
```

And then pass it in to your `multivariate_normal`:

```
dist = multivariate_normal(mu, sigma)
```

Put this into a 2D mapping by:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 40, 41)
y = x.copy()
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
pos = np.empty(xx.shape + (2,))
pos[:, :, 0] = xx
pos[:, :, 1] = yy
my_map = dist.pdf(pos)
```

You'll then have a skewed multivariate normal distribution on a matrix. I suggest you scale this matrix as the values will be small.

Comment: i see that makes alot of sense would you be able to provide the full code to how to implement this, I've never used this library so im having some difficulty implementing it

Comment: dist = multivariate_normal(mu, sigma)
ValueError: the input matrix must be positive semidefinite

Comment: I also cant see a skew in the diagram, i would like for it to skew into the periphery but i cant see that in this diagram. thank you for your help, if you arent able to provide more help i fully understand i appreciate it :)

Comment: @SohrabSalimian The error is my mistake, it's fixed now. The `cov_max` has to be less than the sqrt of the multiplication of the diagonal - and with this it will run. Display your image by `plt.imshow(my_map)`

Comment: the output i get is a small circle in the middle of the diagram, again i cant see the skew in the field but ill keep trying to work on it. if you have any other advice please feel free to provide, maybe even show me what you visualize when you plt.imshow(my_map)

Comment: Oh sorry - I think I misunderstood what skew meant. With this you'll get a covariant distribution with difference length etc .. but I don't have handy code to generate a skew.

Comment: There's the `scipy.stats.skewnorm` module to skew a distribution, but I've yet to figure out how to make it work with 2D.

Comment: ah shoot! well i appreciate the help none the less, maybe you can upvote the question so others can see it as well. or if you have any other resource for me to try thaat would also be super helpful